# Shell script to set up virtualenv and pip

Tags: python-3.x, shell, pip, virtualenv

I'm writing a shell script to set up my virtual env environment and install all related python packages via pip.

```
virtualenv -q -p /usr/bin/python3.5 $1
/bin/bash $1/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

$1 is the name of the virtualenv.
The problem I have is that the pip command does not work in my virtualenv but is executed globally instead.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I created a script to help with my Python workflow: https://github.com/rbrisita/vp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mean to know you have to activate the virtualenv with:

> **source activate**

I am not sure if this can be done from within a shell script, but you can try it as follows:

```
virtualenv -q -p /usr/bin/python3.5 $1
source $1/bin/activate
$1/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
# pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Excerpt from activate:

```
$ cat activate
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly
```

Comment: i'm still having the same issue with `source`. I'm executing the script with `sh virtualenv_script.sh`

Comment: Okay I recognised another issue. I get the message that `source: not found`. I added the shebang `# !/bin/bash` but I still get the message

Comment: `$ type source ... source is a shell builtin` ... Hmmm ... What OS you are using?

Comment: change line 3 to ". $1/bin/activate"

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you've found the solution to your problem, but for future reference, you don't need to activate the virtualenv in order to run pip inside it:

```
#!/bin/bash
virtualenv -q -p /usr/bin/python3.5 $1
$1/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: This wasn't entirely clear to me at first. The missing explanation is that the pip and python commands are in the bin directory inside the virtualenv directory. Activating the virtualenv sets the path and python environment variables so your commands use the binaries in the virtualenv instead of the system files. You can invoke these binaries directly without activating the env, just by referring to them with a path.

Answer (score 3):

What was missing was the shebang 
and I had to start the script using `source myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
virtualenv -q -p /usr/bin/python3.5 $1
source $1/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```